# Adding opacity to setStroke() programmatically

Tags: android, alpha

I am trying to set opacity to Border color using:

```
d.setStroke(5 , Color.parseColor("#4A000000"))
```

The result I get is a border with 50% dark color and 50% of opacity applied.

How to make that to blend like a normal background color, `ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, 100)`?

Comment: Why dont you like the border opacity at 50%? Can you explain what are you trying to achieve more precisely. Cant understand why the result of your code does not fit what you want.

Comment: I am trying to have a border with color and a variable alpha value, so that the border itself would get a transparency blended.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [setStroke()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#setStroke(int,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)),the second parameter is a `ColorStateList`.

And each item in a `ColorStateList` must define an `android:color` attribute like below:

```
<item android:state_enabled="false"
         android:color="?android:attr/colorAccent"
         android:alpha="0.5" />  //use this xml attribute to set opacity.
```

Below is a complete `ColorStateList` example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="@color/sample_focused" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:state_enabled="false"
           android:color="@color/sample_disabled_pressed" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false"
           android:color="@color/sample_disabled_not_pressed" />
   <item android:color="@color/sample_default" 
           android:alpha="0.5"/>
 </selector>
```

After creating a `ColorStateList` resource xml, use it in `setStroke()` method.